# angular2 - bootstrap4 add class for selected custom radio button

Tags: jquery, angular, radio-button

I got some problem with adding `.selected` class to selected custom radio button with using boostrap 4. Here is my code:

**App.component.html**

```html
<div class="list-item item-owner text-center selected" 
     [class.selected]="designation"
     *ngFor="let titleList of designations; let idx = index">
  <p><strong>{{titleList.title}}</strong></p>
  <div class="item-icn icn-owner"></div>
  <p class="tx-desc">
    {{titleList.description}}
  </p>
  <input class="type-owner" type="radio"
         name="designationNewStaff"
         [value]="owner"
         [(ngModel)]="owner" hidden/>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
designations = [];
this.designations = [{
    value: 1,
    data: 'owner',
    title: 'Owner',
    description: 'Manage staff accounts, receive, view &amp; void payment transactions for all stores',
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    data: 'supervisor',
    title: 'Outlet Supervisor',
    description: 'Receive, view & void payment transaction in assigned outlet',
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    data: 'cashier',
    title: 'Outlet Cashier',
    description: 'Receive, view & void payment transaction in assigned outlet',
  }
];
```

Comment: Can you kindly update your question that includes on adding the `selected` class on your custom `radio button`?

Comment: @eeya I already updated in my question. Class suppose to be apply in parent div `class="list-item item-owner text-center selected"`